# Detect fail of chrome.extension.sendRequest

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

Hey fellow Chrome Devs, how would one go about detecting when a `chrome.extension.sendRequest` has failed? I tried this, and no dice:

```
chrome.extension.sendRequest({ /* message stuff here */ }, function(req){
    if(req == null || chrome.extension.lastError == null){
        alert("No response. :(");
    }
});
```

But what happens is that the callback never even fires, which is what I half expected. Is there any way to detect when a sendRequest fails?

Thanks!

Comment: How could `chrome.extension.sendRequest` fail? Maybe you should try `try{}catch(){}`.

Comment: @Derek it could fail because the tab to receive the request has crashed, been closed by the user, or has for some reason unregistered the event, or failed to register it at all.

Answer (score 0):

You need to change....

```
if(req == null || chrome.extension.lastError == null){
    alert("No response. :(");
}
```

...to....

```
if(req == null){
    alert("No response. :( and the error was "+chrome.extension.lastError.message);
}
```

As the docs say for sendRequest `If an error occurs while connecting to the extension, the callback will be called with no arguments and chrome.extension.lastError will be set to the error message.`
http://code.google.com/chrome/extensions/extension.html#method-sendRequest
http://code.google.com/chrome/extensions/extension.html#property-lastError

Answer (score 0):

You could surround it with a `try{}catch(err){}` to catch any errors thrown, but an error is not thrown if there is no response, and there is also no null response.

This would have been done by design, to allow a message receiver to do it's thing. For instance, it might involve a couple of web service requests, or ajax requests that could take a while.

If you know how long it should take to respond, you should implement a timeout (it would have been nice if the sendRequest function included one)

So, you could do something like this:

```
var noResponse = setTimeout(100, function() {
  alert('No response received within 100ms!');
});

chrome.extension.sendRequest({ /* message stuff here */ }, function(req){
  clearTimeout(noResponse);
  alert('I have a response!');
});
```

Comment: I'll probably end up using this solution, but I really don't know how long it will take for it to respond...:/